# Ruby on Rails index routing

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have created an index of an object, request. Request has a address and a body. I set the index to show the address as a link, and I am trying to get the link to go to the show page of that certain object, however it routes me to the create object page.

Routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  get 'quote/new'

  get 'quote/create'

  devise_for :admins

  get '/login',   to: 'sessions#new'
  devise_for :users
  root 'static_pages#home'
  resources :users do
    collection do
      get :signup
      get :login
    post :login
    get :logout
  end
end

  get '/about',   to: 'static_pages#about'
  get '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact'
  get '/signup',  to: 'users#new'
  get '/request', to: 'requests#new'

  get '/account', to: 'users#show'
  get '/show',  to: 'request#show'

  resources :users
  resources :requests

  post '/login',  to: 'users#show'
  delete '/logout',  to: 'sessions#destroy'

end
```

Index html page:

```
<h1>All Requests</h1>

<ul>
  <% @requests.each do |request| %>
    <li>
      <%= link_to request.address, request %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Comment: Request is a really bad model name as you end up masking the request object (the incoming request) and it makes things very confusing to reason about.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, why do you have multiple routes for `requests#show` and `#new`?

```
get '/request', to: 'requests#new'
get '/show', to: 'request#show'
resources :requests
```

Similarly for `User` too..

Or as I can see, you have a custom route for show action, you should limit your routes for `resources` like,

```
resources :requests, except: [:show, :new]
```

Secondly, as suggested by @max, you should think of changing the resource name, `Request` is not a good choice.

Third, for the solution, try naming your path with `as:` option which can be used in your `link_to` option as below,

```
get '/show/:id', to: 'requests#show', as: :request #notice the :id and plurality of action
```

Then in your view,

```
<%= link_to request_path request %>
```

You should checkout the [`docs`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) to understand it better..

Comment: I attempted this and it continued to not work. The links send me to the url "request.1" instead of "requests/1"

Comment: don't pluralize then, try this `get '/show/:id', to: 'request#show', as: :request`